# Have I missed some obvious XSS vulnerabilities?

Tags: php, html, parsing

As the question states: have I missed some obvious security vulnerabilities in this code? Particularly interested in XSS...

I'm trying to create something more robust that [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), but simpler than [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which just feels like overkill.

```
class StripTags {
    private $tags;
    private $dom;
    function __construct($html, $tags = null) {
        // Setup tags
        $this->setTags($tags);

        //Initialise document using provided HTML
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);         //suppress invalid HTML warnings
        $doc_elem = $doc->documentElement;

        $this->traverseAndRemove($doc_elem);

        // Store DOM for processing in __toString()
        $this->dom = $doc;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        // Remove unwanted DOCTYPE etc
        $str = $this->dom->saveHTML();
        $str = str_replace('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">', "", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/^<html><body>/", "", trim($str));
        $str = preg_replace("/<\/body><\/html>$/", "", trim($str));
        return $str;
    }

    private function setTags($t) {
        if (empty($t) or !is_array($t)) {
            $this->tags = array("html", "body", "p", "span", "div", "img", "b", "i", "em", "strong", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "a", "pre");
        } else {
            $this->tags = $t;
        }
        if (!in_array("html",$this->tags)) {
            $this->tags[] = "html";
        }
        if (!in_array("body",$this->tags)) {
            $this->tags[] = "body";
        }
    }

    private function traverseAndRemove(&$elem) {
        // Check node type, attributes and child nodes
        // Reset child/attribute loops if one is removed
        if ($elem->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            $tagName = $elem->tagName;
            if (!in_array($tagName, $this->tags)) {
                // Remove any elements in the tags array and stop processing it
                $elem->parentNode->removeChild($elem);
                return;
            }
            // Check attributes for Javascript events and src/hrefs with javascript too...
            if ($elem->hasAttributes()) {
                $attrs = $elem->attributes;
                for ($i=0,$max=$attrs->length; $i<$max; $i++) {
                    $name = $attrs->item($i)->name;
                    if (in_array($name, array("onload", "onclick","onmouseover","onmousemove","onmousehover","onmousedown","onmouseup", "onunload"))) {
                        $elem->removeAttribute($name);
                        $max--;
                        $i--;
                    }
                    if (in_array($name,array("src", "href")) and preg_match("/^javascript:/i", $attrs->item($i)->value)) {
                        $elem->removeAttribute($name);
                        $max--;
                        $i--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Check all child nodes too
        if ($elem->hasChildNodes()) {
            $children = $elem->childNodes;
            for ($i=0, $max=$children->length; $i<$max; $i++) {
                $this->traverseAndRemove($children->item($i));
                if ($children->length < $max) {
                    $i -= ($max - $children->length);
                    $max = $children->length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to allow users to input a limited subset of tags? if not, the best solution is to throw out everything you've written for sanitizing input, and just make sure the output is encoded.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's to sanitize input from a WYSIWYG editor... we need the customer to be able to have some HTML, but not all

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you explained exactly why you think this approach is more robust than using strip_tags. It will certainly be likely to be a lot slower.

From a quick inspection it doesn't seem to filter CSS behaviours nor data URIs.

If it were me I'd be building on to strip_tags rather than trying to start from scratch.

Comment: strip_tags doesn't validate the HTML, nor can it alter any attributes, which I'd like to be able to do in order to make the "sanitizing" process more robust. How would you build on top of strip_tags instead of starting from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is trying to blacklist stuff is really hard.

Why did you miss `ontouchstart`? What about all the other touch events?

What about `onfocus`?

Why `onmouseover` but not `onmouseleave`?

What about `onerror` on a malformed `img` tag?

What about when a tab is in the middle of `javascript`?

What about when that tab looks like `&#x09;`?

What about when instead `&#x0A;` is in there?

Did you know an image tag doesn't need a 'src'?

Did you forget about lowsrc? What about DYNSRC?

What if the src is encoded in UTF8 code points?

What if the HTML is malformed? (e.g. `<img """><script>alert("hi")</script>">`)

**You will lose trying to do this!**

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet is a great resource, but even that will miss things that are less common.

Be very restrictive, use a good library that covers this, or rethink how you might allow entry.

Markdown for instance + some custom work to allow extra bits and bobs might be a better choice. Look at how this input box works as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Blacklisting unwanted content is a fundamentally flawed approach. The only safe way to defend against XSS attacks is by using white listing.

In other words, define what kind of content you'll allow and delete everything else.